# How to validate only alphanumeric in mobile browser with js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem for validate alphanumeric in mobile browser.

i have code like this.

```
var regex_alphanumeric = /[^[a-z 0-9]]*/gi;

$('#address').keypress(function (e) {
  if(e.key.match(regex_alphanumeric)){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

with this code, only support for desktop browser, but if i check in **mobile browser**, validate alpha numeric not running well because in mobilebrowser e.key value always 229

how to check alphanumeric in mobilebrowser?

Comment: Please see [Allowing only Alphanumeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236651/allowing-only-alphanumeric-values) probably you can find your answer.

Comment: Or: event.key is undefined in mobile browsers for keyup, keydown and keypress
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45436329/6352710

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal. it's only work on desktop browser. but in mobile browser charCode always return 229.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official
>   specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may
>   differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552368/2809176).

[One more solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157786/2809176) to take a previous char.

Comment: thanks for helping, but in android or iphone, keydown or keyup can't work for validate alphanumeric. because "keycode" always 229, and "key" always undefined. i need validate alphanumeric on android / iphone browser with realtime validate

Comment: @teguh11, the answer is updated. Please have a look.